# How can I make the "Azure Service Bus" message be handled by a single server instance from the instance pool?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I have an Asp.Net core Web Api running in the Azure App Service.
I also want to make a BackgroundWorker that will periodically browse the database. And if there are necessary records send a message via Azure Bus to WebApi, WebApi should send notifications to mobile devices when receiving the message.

In case there is only one instance of WebApi, there is no question. But autoscaling is enabled. That is, with a high load there can be a lot of WebApi. And when a message is sent by BackgroundWorker , it will be received by many services, and repeatedly duplicate sending notification to the user.

Is there already a ready mechanism which is used in such situations? A lot of subscribers to the message, all of them can receive it, but if one received it, no one else should receive it.

Comment: are you using Service Bus Queues or Topics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Recieve modes:

- ReceiveAndDelete
- PeekLock

Both will work in your case, in that the first consumer to get the message, gets it, and the others will not see it.

The difference is in what happens if something crashes. With ReceiveAndDelete the message is lost and will not be processed. With PeekLock depending on how far it got before the crash, the message may be processed twice.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to the queue? Is ReceiveAndDelete possible when using Topic?

Comment: Yes this applies to queues. Topics are for sending the same message to many subscribers. So either you need to use queues or have some logic for the first subscriber that reads the message to say that he is going to process it.

Comment: I got it, thanks. I just thought there was a built-in mechanism Topic + ReceiveAndDelete. So I'll have to make something up myself.